# Como hago para actualizar correctamente un correctamente un useState dentro de un useEffect

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

Estoy desarrollando una aplicación web que muestra una lista de posts. Tengo dos botones que permiten alternar entre mostrar los posts más recientes y los más populares. El problema que estoy enfrentando es que al hacer clic en uno de estos botones para cambiar el orden de los posts, la lista de posts existente no se borra y los nuevos posts se agregan, lo que resulta en una lista que se alarga cada vez más cada vez que se cambia el orden.

Mi componente principal (App) se encarga de cargar los datos del backend. Tengo dos useEffect que controlan la carga de posts y la limpieza de la lista de posts cuando cambia el orden. Sin embargo, parece que la limpieza de la lista de posts no está funcionando como se esperaba.

```
  function App() {
    ...
    const [page, setPage] = useState(0);
    const [order, setOrder] = useState("new");
    const prevOrder = useRef(null);

    async function fetchPosts(){
      let posts = await fetch(`http://localhost:3001/post/all?page=${page}&order=${order}`,
      {
        headers: new Headers({
          "Authorization": token
        })
      }
      );
      let postsJSON = await posts.json();   
      if(postsJSON.length > 0){
        setLastPosts([...lastPosts, ...postsJSON]);
      }
    }
  
    useEffect(() => {
      async function fetchData() {
        let tk = localStorage.getItem("token");
        if (tk != null) {
          try {
            const response = await fetch('http://localhost:3001/authorize/check', {
              headers: new Headers({
                "Authorization": tk
              })
            });
            if (!response.ok) {
              throw new Error('Error al obtener los datos');
            }
            setToken(tk);
            setLogged(true);
            setUsername(localStorage.getItem("username"));
            fetchPosts(tk);
          } catch (error) {
            console.error('Error al obtener los datos:', error);
          }
        }
      };
  
      fetchData();
  
      return () => {
        // Realizar limpieza, si es necesario
      };
    }, [page, order]);
  
    useEffect(() => {
      console.log("Prev: " + prevOrder.current);
      console.log("Current: " + order);
  
      // Si el modo de orden cambia, limpiamos la lista de posts
      if (order !== prevOrder.current) {
        prevOrder.current = order;
        console.log("Prev: " + prevOrder.current);
        setPage(0);
        setLastPosts([]); // Limpiamos la lista de posts
        fetchPosts(); // Llamamos a fetchPosts para cargar los nuevos posts
      }
    }, [order]);

  ...
```

Comment: Así como esta el código siempre va a limpiar la lista en el segundo `useEffect` porque `prevOrder` siempre es `null`, entonces muestra la parte del código que opera con prevOrder, puede que este en los handlers de tus botones, se necesita mas información...